# PC performance testing - Whetstone and Dhrystone for c#

Tags: c#, .net, performance-testing

I'm searching for some ideas or algorithms of PC performance testing during `integer`, `float` and `string` operations, like Whetstone and Dhrystone.
Are there some for the .net runtime?

I'm going to implement similar function by myself, and want to know more about this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the source code for whetstone; you could easily port this to C#: [whetstone.c](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/whetstone.c).  Also available on that site is dhrystone: [dhrystone.c](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/dhry-c).  They're pretty old, but there are lots of benchmark programs available on [netlib.org](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/).